# AnimationController The named parameter 'vsync' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, animationcontroller

AnimationController stopped working because somehow vsync is not a named parameter anymore.

This line of code stopped working.

`controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this);`

It now shows an error saying:

```
The named parameter 'vsync' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'vsync'.dartundefined_named_parameter
```

I use this exact same code in two different apps, in one of them I just removed the fading text animation as a hot fix, but on the other app I need a real fix. Has anyone seen this problem recently?

Note:

-This exact same code has been working for months and stopped working after an update.

-The surrounding class does have: `with TickerProviderStateMixin`

```
class FadingText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final int seconds;
  final TextStyle style;

  FadingText({this.text, this.seconds, this.style});

  @override
  _FadingTextState createState() => _FadingTextState();
}

class _FadingTextState extends State<FadingText> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: Text(widget.text, style: widget.style,),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: widget.seconds), vsync: this);
    animation = Tween(begin: 0.5, end: 1.0).animate(controller);

    animation.addStatusListener((status) {
      if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) { controller.reverse(); }
      else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) { controller.forward(); }
    });

    controller.forward();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

```
Flutter Doctor


[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.21.0-6.0.pre.140, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-MX)
    • Flutter version 1.21.0-6.0.pre.140 at /Users/luisharo/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 7884420a0a (25 hours ago), 2020-07-31 20:20:00 +0200
    • Engine revision 280bbfc763
    • Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-2.0.dev bd528bfbd6)

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/luisharo/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.8052

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.1

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • JKM LX3 (mobile)       • 7MLNW19723003608                     • android-arm64  • Android 9 (API 28)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 675C24C4-7682-4DFE-8037-062893405EE7 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5
      (simulator)
    • Web Server (web)       • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Could you post your class constructor? And where you tried to implement your Controller?

Comment: Hi Mariano, I posted an edit with the whole class.

Comment: could you also post your "flutter doctor -v"? Is the same issue happening using the single ticker provider?

Comment: Do you have another class with the same name maybe?

Comment: I added the results of flutter doctor -v... also checked that the class is not duplicated.

Comment: Same error if trying with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin

Comment: I am currently running into the same issue. This is probably a bug introduce since the last update... Try to open an issue on the [flutter GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) page it should be fixed quickly if this issue is as spread as I think. By checking here : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/a7e868dd876f4b84462cc29fa2dd4092280a1d7a#diff-82a88b0b4aa73ca8c85c9fc068be95b6 You can see the modifications made 4 days ago.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In your `pubspec.yml`

change this to:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"
```

and `flutter pub get`

in Android Studio invalidate the cache and restart, you should be good to go.

Credit : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62752#issuecomment-667744745

Comment: to "invalidate the cache and restart" in android studio click (File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart)

Comment: As for me I need one more step is reload IDE :D Thanks, it works like a charm.

Comment: for VSCode, do 'Restart Analysis Server', ctrl+shift+p to bring up the command palette and type 'analysis' to search for it. This will save you from restarting the IDE

Answer (score 35):

What happened is that `@required` syntax was migrated during the rollout of null-safety to now just be `required`. This is valid new-Dart, but if you upgrade with your editor open, it will have stale build rules. Simply run `flutter clean` and restart your IDE, and that should do it.

Hopefully no need to restart your computer, change internet providers, etc.

Comment: Editor Restart fixed it

Answer (score 23):

A few things (unfortunately not pinpointed) that help me with issues like this:

***edit: I would recommend doing these in order, hopefully the issue will be solved before you reach the end of the list.*

- run flutter upgrade
- run flutter pub get
- run flutter clean
- restart IDE
- change flutter channel
- and in this case,
  change minimum SDK version from 2.7.0 to 2.8.0.

There are, of course, caveats to a few of these tactics. More experienced developers would surely have more details to offer, but I haven't encountered issues with this approach.

Comment: Only doing the first four steps solved the issue.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same issue after upgrading flutter. Restarting the IDE fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue when I upgraded to Flutter 1.22.

I am using VS Code.

Simply run: `Flutter Clean` in the Terminal and restart your IDE. That should fix the problem!

Answer (score 8):

if you still getting same error with vsync: this
you probably don't have  **with TickerProviderStateMixin** in your State definition

correct your state definition like this

```
class _BookListState extends State<BookList> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final BookHelper _bookHelper = BookHelper.instance;
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, thank

Answer (score 5):

I have given 5 steps and apply all the steps in the same order as mentioned and I think your problem will be solved.

Step 1: Change the SDK version in the pubspec.yaml to 2.8

```
environment:
sdk: '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'
```

Step 2: Open terminal and run

```
flutter upgrade
```

Step 3: After Step 2, get all the package by running this command

```
flutter pub get
```

Step 4: Then use this command to clean flutter

```
flutter clean
```

Step 5: Close the IDE (like VS Code, Android Studio) and then reopen it.
That's all!!!

vsync will appear back again.

Apart from vsync, the colors property in LinearGradient was also missing and after I applied all these steps, colors property along with vsync reappeared.

Answer (score 4):

After upgrading flutter.

1. Restarting the IDE
2. If necessary, reboot your computer

Answer (score 3):

**How did I solve it in Android Studio ?**

Firstly, previous answers can be wrong because *I did not change my SDK range*:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0<3.0.0"
```

I wrote code (*vsync*) in my dart file and I know Android Studio shows error but **do not care**, just write your code:

```
AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(
  duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
  vsync: this,
);
```

After that, close your project and then open it again. System can understand by itself. That's all ! *You can see my screen shot proof*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

how about add this,

class _AnimationScreenState extends State 
///

```
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
```

///
}

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it did help me ! Without it, you cannot use `this` for the parameter `vsync`

Answer (score 1):

Just restarting the IDE solves this issue for me

and don't forget to inheritate Tickerprovider.

Comment: I first change `sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"` in `pubspec.ym`l and then a restart, not sure which one solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue, I upgraded the SDK and then did Invalidate caches and Restart and It worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything `just invalid the cache and restart your IDE`

1. flutter clean
2. restart your IDE

Answer (score 1):

You have to place that line inside initState() method, as follow:

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
_controller = AnimationController(duration: expandDuration, vsync: this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I resolved the issue after setting the dart and flutter SDK path in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Change the SDK version in the pubspec.yaml to '>=2.8.0 <3.0.0'

Then Run following commands :

- flutter upgrade
- flutter pub get
- flutter clean

And Restart IDE

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
with TickerProviderStateMixin
```

with

```
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin
```

worked for me.